# django-guardian - meaning of (User, 'username', 'username')

Tags: django, decorator, django-guardian

Can anyone explain me, what does `(User, 'username', 'username')` and `(User, 'username', 'username', 'groups__name', 'group_name')` mean?

```
@permission_required('auth.change_user', return_403=True)
def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello')

@permission_required('auth.change_user', (User, 'username', 'username'))
def my_view(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    return user.get_absolute_url()

@permission_required('auth.change_user',
    (User, 'username', 'username', 'groups__name', 'group_name'))
def my_view(request, username, group_name):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username,
        group__name=group_name)
    return user.get_absolute_url()
```

Taken here: http://pythonhosted.org/django-guardian/api/guardian.decorators.html

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> Optionally, instances for which check should be made may be passed as
>   an second argument or as a tuple parameters same as those passed to
>   get_object_or_404 but must be provided as pairs of strings.

So if you want to check permission of one `User` model instance, you can pass the tuple in order `(ModelName, argname, varname)` (note that `argname` and `varname` should be in pair) like:

```
(User, 'username', 'username')
```

It's the same as parameters in `get_object_or_404()` function:

```
get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
```

And similar if you have tuple `(User, 'username', 'username', 'groups__name', 'group_name')`...

You can check the source code for more understanding: https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian/blob/master/guardian/decorators.py#L74